# Taskbar notification icon Show/Hide setting lost on program upgrade

Tags: visual-studio-2010, taskbar

I have a Visual Studio 2010 .NET program that always has an icon in the Windows 7 taskbar.  When the program is intially installed on a computer, I go to the notification settings screen, find my program, and set it to "Show icon and notifications".  This works well, and "sticks" even if the computer is rebooted.

However, when I publish an upgrade to the program (this is done by incrementing the Assembly Version number), this setting reverts back to "Only show notifications".  I realize technically that this is a "new" executable, which is probably causing this behaviour, but I find this highly annoying.

Is there any way to change this setting for **all versions** of my program?  Or some way to increment my assembly version so this doesn't happen?  I can't believe that other programs (like MS Outlook) require resetting this setting each time there is an incremental program update.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: I have this same issue with 2013 Visual Studio. Am yet to find a fix for it.